# How to send IPMI commands over I2C?

Tags: linux-device-driver, i2c, raspberry-pi4, ipmi, ipmitool

I am looking into trying to run `ipmitool` over I2C and was wondering if this is supported. I have a raspberry Pi connected via I2C to another device that has a BMC. I have the character device `/dev/i2c-1` which I can use to write I2C commands to but I am hoping to be able to send IPMI commands instead, such as with `ipmitool`.

If I connect the Pi and other system both to the same network, I can still send commands over ipmitool's `lanplus` interface but that is not what I want to do. I would like to see if sending them over I2C is possible.

Most commands I run with `ipmitool` seem to attempt to open the file `/dev/ipmi-N` which doesn't exist on my raspberry pi. I checked the driver support in the kernel for getting that (https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/driver-api/ipmi.html) and made sure that my kernel has `ipmi_msghandler`, `ipmi_devintf`, and `ipmi_ssif` compiled into it. But still no luck. I suspect the issue is that I haven't correctly configured the `ipmi_ssif` driver on the kernel command line. Am I on the right path with this? I determined the i2c address with `i2cdetect -y 1` and it shows up as `0x10`. Dumping the file `cat /sys/class/i2c-adapter/i2c-1/name` shows me that my adapter is `bcm2835`. This led me to try to add `ipmb_ssif.addr=0x10 ipmi_ssif.adapter=bcm2835 ipmi_ssif.dbg=1,2,4,8 ipmi_ssif.dbg_probe=1` to the kernel command line. However, I didn't specify anything for `ipmi_ssif.slave_addrs`, `ipmi_ssif.tryacpi`, or `ipmi_ssif.trydmi` which admittedly could be my problem. I don't know if it could also be just something with the raspberry Pi maybe not having some support for this or something. Any ideas?

I also tried the driver `ipmi_si`, although the Pi doesn't seem to have the hardware support for this. I suspect that's trying to access a BMC locally instead of trying to go over I2C. Since the `ipmi_ssif` talks about going over an SMBus that seemed like the one that I wanted.

I did also looked through some of the other interfaces that `ipmitool` supports and went down a bit of a rabbit hole with the ipmb-dev-int driver (https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/driver-api/ipmb.html) since that also looked promising and originally mistook it for imb interface. But it doesn't look like `ipmitool` has that as an interface. But perhaps there is another one there that might be a better option for what I am trying to do. Maybe the *free* interface for working with `freeipmi`?

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I posted a similar question to the folks who maintain `ipmitool` https://github.com/ipmitool/ipmitool/discussions/296 and one of the maintainers there helped me out by pointing me to another ipmb driver https://github.com/Mellanox/ipmb-host that looks like I might be able to use in combination with the OpenIPMI interface.